# Seaching a File in Unix for a given string and then another set of Strings within this file and print file properties too

Tags: grep, find, xargs

I am using command to search for files staring from a given Directory in Unix  , files ending `*.sas`  and containing the string `DB2`. I then inturn want to search the resultant set of  files for the Strings `DSN=` or `DATASRC=` and also print the line containing these strings. So this is the FInd command I am using :

```
find '/shrproj/'  -type f -name '*.sas'  -exec  grep   -il 'DB2'  {} \;  2> /dev/null  |  xargs   egrep   -Ri  'DSN=|DATASRC='
```

This gives me the desired ouput:

```
/shrproj/files/stp_code/aea_aat_stp/icrv3/bin/macro/cnct_2_eaw.sas:                   ,"DSN=%UPCASE(&the_database.)"
/shrproj/files/stp_code/aea_aat_stp/icrv3/bin/macro/cnct_2_eaw.sas:                   ,"DSN=%UPCASE(&the_database.)"
```

But now i also want to print the properties of the file (using the -ls option) following the above result ie the below is what i intend to achieve :

```
/shrproj/files/stp_code/aea_aat_stp/icrv3/bin/macro/cnct_2_eaw.sas:                   ,"DSN=%UPCASE(&the_database.)"
/shrproj/files/stp_code/aea_aat_stp/icrv3/bin/macro/cnct_2_eaw.sas:                   ,"DSN=%UPCASE(&the_database.)"
61522   19 -rwxrwsr-x  1 sas       sas          18546 Jun  2  2010 /shrproj/files/stp_code/aea_aat_stp/icrv3/bin/macro/cnct_2_eaw.sas
```

The Properties of the file in the last line above is the same when using the find command with -ls option.

```
 find /shrproj/files/stp_code/aea_aat_stp/icrv3/bin/macro/cnct_2_eaw.sas -ls
```

So how do i achieve this this for each and every file using the very first Find command i am using above ?.

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Do not [double post questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26938020/3076724)!

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
find '/shrproj/'  -type f -name '*.sas' \
    -exec  grep -iq 'DB2'  {} \; \
    -exec  grep -ie  DSN= -e DATASRC= {} \; \
    -ls
```

Comment: I understand this just fine, but I feel obligated to ask you to explain it for the benefit of the OP and future readers.

Comment: It works because `-exec` will take the exit status of whatever command it executes and use it logically in `find`. And `find` logic dictates that there is an implied short-circuit `-a` (AND) linking any options that are not otherwise separated by operators. Also, worth noting that `grep PATTERN FILE` [should have the same exit status on non-error cases as -q](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168296/60101). I was under the mistaken impression that `-q` was different when posting my answer to the same question on SO (which added some redundant options). So this is definitely the best answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest something along the lines of this (can't do everything in a one-liner) ;-)

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(find '/shrproj/' -type f -name '*.sas'); do
 G1="$(grep -il 'DB2' "$i")"
 if [ -n "$G1" ]; then
  G2="$(egrep -Ri 'DSN=|DATASRC=' "$i")"
  if [ -n "$G2" ]; then
   echo "$G1"
   echo "$G2"
   ls -l "$i"
  fi
 fi
done
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```