# Conditional grep without quiet option

Tags: bash, grep

I always thought the quiet (`-q`) option had to be used when using `grep` conditionally. But re-reading the `man` page it seems like it should work without it.

So if you want to print matches and use it in a conditional, can you just do something like

```
grep PATTERN FILE && do_something_else
```

The only thing that makes me uncertain is that there appears to be a slight difference in exit status.

With `-q`,

- grep will "exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, **even if an error was detected**".

Without `-q`

- "The  exit  status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if not found.  **If an error occurred the exit status is 2**".

But I can't think of an example where the difference will become noticeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
$ echo "foo" > file
$ grep foo file wrongfile; echo "Exit status: $?"
file:foo
grep: wrongfile: No such file or directory
Exit status: 2
$ grep -q foo file wrongfile;  echo "Exit status: $?"
Exit status: 0
```

So, we have a file called `file` that contains the string `foo`. When I ran `grep` with `-q` on `file` and the nonexistent `wrongfile`, since `file` contained a match, `grep` exited with `0` status despite the "No such file" error.

Comment: +1 didn't think about the case with more than one file, is there any difference with 1?

Comment: @BroSlow this was the first case that came to mind where you can find both an error _and_ a hit. I can't think of any way to get both an error and a hit with one file. Perhaps if the file is truncated while it is being read but that's hard to test.